# (upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream) ..... && 502 bad gateway

Tags: nginx, webserver, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I am getting this error log in /var/log/nginx. When I run the site I get a 502 bad gateway after exactly 30 seconds of loading up. If i remove some (time extensive) lines of code everything works fine. I edited the nginx config file but I dont think thats the problem.

I went to: /etc/nginx/sites-available/django and this is the config I have

```sh
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket fail_timeout=0;
     }

     server {
          listen 80 default_server;
           listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/media;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/static;
    }

    # Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
    location /static/admin {
       alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist- 
     packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_read_timeout 110s;
            proxy_send_timeout 110s;
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
   }
}
```

I think I need to change the timeout in the gunicorn config file, but I dont know where that is. I could not find it.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep worker_processes /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
worker_processes auto;
```

change worker processes from "1" to "auto"

use this in your config

```
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 1h;
ssl_buffer_size 4k;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you were able to solve this, it is from 2018 I see, but just in case someone is having the same issue. I am using pm2 with --watch, so every time I uploaded I file, because it was being saved in the uploads folder the app will restart, hence the error, so if in you are using pm2 with --watch and in someway a file is being changed this will restart your node app, causing that upstream issue.